# Let $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ be linear independent vectors and $v$ a linear combination of those. Are $v_1-v,\ldots, v_n-v$ still linear independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ be linear independent vectors and $v$ a linear combination of those, i.e. there are $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $v=\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_jv_j$. However, $v\ne v_j$ for any $j\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$.

Is it true, that $v_1-v,\ldots, v_n-v$ are still linear independent?

For $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n\in\mathbb{R}$, I find

$$0=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j(v_j-v)=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_jv_j-(\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j)v$$
such that

$$(\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j)\sum_{k=1}^n\beta_kv_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_kv_k$$
and

$$\alpha_k=(\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j)\beta_k$$

Can I deduce from this, that $\alpha_k=0$?

Comment: It's a dupe. Have you already searched for duplicate?

Comment: No, I didn't find this particular one.

Comment: This one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222596/linearly-independent-vectors-each-subtracted-by-a-linear-combination-of-them-are?rq=1

Comment: Try $v_1=(1, 0), v_2=(0, 1) $ and $v=(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) $

Comment: Ok, but this means, I can show linear independence, if $\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_j\ne 1$?

Comment: Try simple examples. If $v_1,v_2$ are li. what about $0, v_2-v_1$???

Comment: I am in a particular situation, with $\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_j\ne 1$. This implies linear independence, right?